# Detailed API call descriptions not available in x64dbg

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

I am following a RE tutorial, and the guy is using Ollydbg while I use x64dbg... and I don't find all the descriptions in that Olly has, and it's quite annoying !
There is an example from the two programs running the same Reverseme :
[image: x64dbg screenshot]

[image: Ollydbg screenshot]

How can I enable the same detailed descriptions in x64dbg? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, x64dbg doesn't have a feature to show Win API call descriptions unlike OllyDbg.

For that, you need to use a plugin like [xAnalyzer](https://github.com/ThunderCls/xAnalyzer) or the older [APIInfo Plugin](https://github.com/mrfearless/APIInfo-Plugin-x86).

Comment: +100 ! You entirely answered my question ! Tanks !

Comment: Glad to help! You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark. Thanks.