# How to see parameters in stack in x64dbg like in OllyDbg for known API calls?

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

Based on [Detailed API call descriptions not available in x64dbg](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22368/detailed-api-call-descriptions-not-available-in-x64dbg)

When I debug a known API call like for example WSARecv, in OllyDbg I can nicely see the parameters in the stack:

[image]

I've installed both plugins: xAnalyzer & APIInfo

[image]

[image]

But I can't get x64dbg (in this case x32dbg) to show the parameters like Olly:

[image]

I tried to `right click in CPU window -> xAnalyzer -> Analyze module` but didn't make any difference...

Right now I'm using OllyDbg and x32dbg simoultaneusly only because of this... How can I see in x32dbg the parameters like I can see nicely in Olly?

Comment: Looks like OllyDbg don't die because of this little details :D